# Oracle DB connection issue

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

When I try to connect java application to oracle db using jdbc thin client, my system name was sent to db server without host name (eg. 102XXXXX) But when I try with oracle client(PL/SQL developer), my system name was sent to db server with domain name appended (eg. North_America/102XXXXX). And in oracle server, my machine is whitelisted with domain name (eg. North_America/102XXXXX). So I got account locked exception  when try to run the java application but have successful connection from PL/SQL developer. I am not sure how to solve this issue from my side. I need both connection. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Got resolved from oracle db server team by white listing my machine. Nothing to do from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can also customize what the Oracle JDBC thin driver sends for the system name during authentication by setting this property `"v$session.machine"`.